# How can I ask what number of time it is of the person doing something in correct and concise way?

Tags: grammar, questions, transformation

The **answer** I'd like to receive upon my question is this:

> It is my 4th.

The **question** I'd like to ask is something like this:

> 1. What timeth is it you are trying to do this?, or
> 2. What timeth you are trying to do this?, or
> 3. How many timeth ... (1.) and (2.)

I hope I am clear.

I still cannot find out how I should edit my question in a few examples that would yield the answer I want. Could you help? This has been for so long on my mind, at last I found a place to ask help

Comment: Timeth? Do you mean "times"?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether this question is asking for the position of a person in a sequence or how often something has been done... "How many presidents have there been" vs. "What number president was FDR?" Because of this, I am hesitant to dupe close this until the OP explains what they're asking more clearly.

Comment: Probably a duplicate, but the simplest way to ask this is **"How many times have you tried to do this?"**